# Problem with proof of Stone Representation Theorem

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, filters

I am reading Thomas Jech's *Axiom of choice* in which he gives a concise proof of the Stone Representation theorem using the (Boolean) Prime Ideal theorem. However he states something is trivial, which I am really struggling to see. I shall quote him verbatim:

Stone Representation theorem: Every Boolean algebra is isomorphic to a set algebra. (Set algebra is an algebra on a family of sets with + = union, $\cdot$ = intersection, - = complement)

Proof: Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra, let 
$$S = \{U:U \textrm{ is an ultrafilter on }B\}$$
for $u\in B$ let $\pi(u) = \{U\in S:u\in U\}$. Then it is easy to see that 
$$\pi(u+v)=\pi(u)\cup\pi(v)$$
$$\pi(u\cdot v)=\pi(u)\cap\pi(v)$$
$$\pi(-u) = \pi(u)^C$$
Now, I can understand the last line: $U \in \pi(-u)$ iff $-u \in U$ iff $u \notin U$ iff $U \in \pi(u)^C$ (as $U$ an ultrafilter, so xor $u\in U$ or $-u \in U$. 
But I cannot see how to show the other two lines. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U\in S$ and $u,v\in B$.  If $u,v\in U$, then $u\cap v\in U$ since $U$ is a filter.  Conversely, if $u\cdot v\in U$, then $u\in U$ and $v\in U$, since $u\cdot v\leq u$ and $u\cdot v\leq v$ and $U$ is a filter.  Thus $\pi(u\cdot v)=\pi(u)\cap\pi(v)$.  The other equation then follows formally: $$\pi(u+v)=\pi(-(-u\cdot-v))=(\pi(u)^C\cap\pi(v)^C)^C=\pi(v)\cup\pi(v).$$

Comment: In his notes, Jech writes that $u \le v$ iff $u+v = v$. Can you explain why $u\cdot v \le u$? I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: $u\cdot v+u=u\cdot v+u\cdot 1=u\cdot (v+1)=u\cdot 1=u$.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Jech's book handy, but I'd expect that, before getting to anything as fancy as ultrafilters and the Stone representation theorem, he'd point out that $u\cdot v$ is the greatest lower bound of $u$ and $v$.  That includes the information that $u\cdot v\leq u$.